# PostgreSQL - How to save a parameter (array) into single records

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameters, sql-insert, insert-into

Here's my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_array(arraynumbers integer[], arraystrings text[])
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO employees (id, name)
VALUES (arraynumbers[0], arraystrings[0]),
       (arraynumbers[1], arraystrings[1]),
       (arraynumbers[2], arraystrings[2])
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

How do I implement a loop to save each index of the arrays as a new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `insert ... select` together with `unnest()`. And you don't need PL/pgSQL for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_array(arraynumbers integer[], arraystrings text[])
  RETURNS void 
AS $$
  insert into employees(id, name)
  select unnest(arraynumbers), unnest(arraystrings);
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```